# How many terraform tftstates should one have in their multiple environments?

Tags: terraform

I am however a bit confused with how many `tfstates` should one have per environment. I understand that each environment be it in `stage/prod/dev` should have their own `tfstate` separately. But does that mean that there should only be one `tfstate` in each environment (e.g: one for a stage, one for prod, and one for dev) total of three `tftstates`, where all configs that reside in that environment will be recorded? Or should each environment have multiple `tftstates` (e.g: stage will have `tftstate` for `vpc config`, another `tftstate` for frontend-apps config, another `tftstate` for backend-apps… etc) and similarly with prod and dev?

Comment: There is a nice post I read on terraform which explains why you should have more than one tftstate but I dont know how many to have per environment. 

https://charity.wtf/2016/03/30/terraform-vpc-and-why-you-want-a-tfstate-file-per-env/

Answer (score 0):

I played around bunch of stuff for state management and keeping everything separate. You are right to have a separate state for each environment.

This may not be as per the suggestions you will come across on internet. ie. to create separate folder and have state on default environment.

I am maintaining state for an individual workspace with workspace naming specific to client-env with single S3 bucket and dynamodb for state and locking.

Terraform keeps them separate w.r.t workspace prefix and S3 bucket looks like this.

```
-terraform (workspace-prefix)
     -clientA-ENV-A
     -clientA-ENV-B
     -clientB-ENV-A
     ...
```

I run the same terraform recipe for all clients and env so no copy paste of any code.

Multiple users can work on the client and env specific workspace and it helps my CI/CD to not do repetitive inits.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Pat. So does that mean that there should be one tfstate file per environment? This tfstate file will contain all records of vpc/security/asg/ec2...etc. services. And it will be referenced every time a deployment is made within that environment?

Comment: Yes, if you have s3 bucket as backend configuration you would have folder for each workspace and state file to that workspace in that folder. folder structure created in below format `workspace-prefix/workspace-name/(path-to-key)` I have named workspace-prefix as `terraform` path-to-key as `terraform.tfstate` giving me `terraform/myworkspace/terraform.tfstate`

Comment: Pat, thank you for clearing it up. Much appreciated!

Comment: I am also in the same boat of learning so glad to be helpful :)